# Google CloudSQL (MySQL) error when trying to connect: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'google mysql ip here'

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I need to connect from MySQL Administrator client on my workstation to the Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) instance, in order to configure users in MySQL database so that my deployed applications on App Engine can use another database I imported into the Cloud SQL instance.

I am getting this error for some reason.

I've authorized access to MySQL instance on Google Cloud SQL using CDIR and exact IP:
xxxx.xxxx.0.0/1
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you re-check the Cloud SQL IP address, Authorized IP address (of your workstation), username and password that you are using to connect.

If you are behind a proxy could you the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control#appaccess) to ensure you are using the right Authorized IP address.

If everything is as expected and you still cannot connect please contact us at cloud-sql@google.com with your instance name and we will look into the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I solved this, there is a bug in MySQL Workbench/Administrator client for Windows...  I will answer my own question now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to log into MySQL instance from another location (home) by authorizing my home IP.  It originally has not worked when I tried connecting from work.

Somehow my co-worker can use MySQL Workbench to log in, but he has another version of the client program.

Clearly some issue with the MySQL Workbench client version that I have - 6.1.6.11834.